# can you view SharePoint 2013 through the permissions of another user?

Tags: 2013

With Full Control, can I view SharePoint as another user would, with his/her permission, as if I was navigating the site with a lower permission level?

I receive questions about not having access to certain parts of my SharePoint site and I would like to view these sites as the user to understand better what they are seeing and experiencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not.  You have to use an account with same privileges to replicate such behavior.  SharePoint 2013 does not have an easy to reach UI function for logging in as another user.  I tend to just run a new browser session as the test account I want to use.

For the sake of completeness. You can append this to the URL of your site to have SP2013 request new credentials

```
/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true
```

Depending on how you have your browser configured however (stored credentials, cache, password manager add-in ,etc), it may be more work using that method then simply executing a "run as" session on the browser itself.